# FullCalendar Scheduler. Event overlaped, when resize, the event is moving order

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler, fullcalendar-3

I meet an issue with Jquery FullCalendar Scheduler. I have many events on one resource (they are with overlap:true). It's okey for the moment. But when I want to resize one for exemple extend the end, if it places on the first place. Or if the event is dragged and dropped later, the event order is moved.

I did a codepen exemple where you can see the problem:
[CodePen](https://codepen.io/guillaumekolly/pen/zyENmL?editors=1111)

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  dragScroll: false,
  droppable: true,
  overlap: true,
  scrollTime: '00:00',...
```

Do you know if there is any option to avoid this behaviour, I don't think it's a "bug" because if the dates of to events are consecutive, (one finish and the other begin the next day for exemple), it should align on the same line.. So I guess this behaviour is normal. But to not confused my users when I have like 10 events on same dates, I would like to not move the event places.

Do you have any idea or any hack to avoid this behavious ?

Thanks for help.